# Inno Setup Change AppName based on component(s) selected

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need the installer to show different `AppName` based on (un)selected components. I tried this:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName={code:GetAppName}
AppVersion=1.0
AppVerName=Dagon Video Tools
AppId=Dagon Video Tools
DefaultDirName={sd}\Games\Dagon Video Tools

[Code]
function GetAppName(Value: string): string;
var
  CurPageID: Integer;
Begin
  Result := 'Dagon Video Tools'
  if (CurPageID=wpSelectComponents) and IsComponentSelected('Slasher') and not IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') then
    begin
      Result := 'Dagon Slasher';
    end;
  if (CurPageID=wpSelectComponents) and IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') and not IsComponentSelected('Slasher') then
    begin
      Result := 'Dagon Frankenstein';
    end;
  if (CurPageID=wpSelectComponents) and IsComponentSelected('Slasher') and IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') then
    begin
      Result := 'Dagon Video Tools';
    end;
End;
```

But, as you can guess, this doesn't work. Is this script incomplete or should it be done in a different way altogether?

Comment: Window Title - doesn't matter,
FinishedLabel - preferably,
The whole uninstall process - should be changed,
Add/Remove Programs - should be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `AppName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname) value is resolved (= your `GetAppName` is called) immediately after [the `InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) (if any) finishes. That is a long before the user is able to change the components.

So you cannot make `AppName` depend on the selected components.

Some uses of the `AppName` could be overridden with a custom value though, but not all. *See below.*

---

Though, as I know that your question is actually about a setup type, you can do this:

- Create custom "type" page (like a menu) as the very first one.
- Once the user selects the "type", restart the installer with a custom switch (e.g. `/APPTYPE=slasher`) and exit.
- Once the installer is (re-)run with the `/APPTYPE`, you know from the beginning, what component/type you are installing and hence you can set the `AppName` normally.
- Of course, you skip the custom "type" page.

This is actually a way simpler to implement. The only drawback is that the setup window is "recreated" after the user selects the "type".

---

*This is the original response in case you do not want to use the above solution.*

First, your implementation of the `GetAppName` is wrong. You are using an uninitialized variable `CurPageID`. And anyway, as mentioned already, the `GetAppName` is called even before the wizard window is created, so "current page" is irrelevant here.

The correct implementation would be like:

```pascal
function GetAppName(Value: string): string;
begin
  if IsComponentSelected('Slasher') and not IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') then
  begin
    Result := 'Dagon Slasher';
  end
    else
  if IsComponentSelected('Frankenstein') and not IsComponentSelected('Slasher') then
  begin
    Result := 'Dagon Frankenstein';
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := 'Dagon Video Tools';
  end;
end;
```

But this still won't make it working in the `AppName` directive. We will use it in other contexts though later.

*Also note that for [your specific installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735386/850848), you should better use [the `WizardSetupType(false)` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsetuptype) instead of the `IsComponentSelected`.*

---

**FinishedLabel**

Just override the Inno Setup default text in `CurPageChanged(wpFinished)`:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  S: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    S := SetupMessage(msgFinishedHeadingLabel);
    StringChange(S, '[name]', GetAppName(''));
    WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption := S;
    WizardForm.AdjustLabelHeight(WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel);
    { Ideally we should shift the FinishedLabel up or down here, }
    { if the height of the header changed. }

    { Note that other messages (msgFinishedLabelNoIcons or msgFinishedRestartLabel) }
    { are used in special situations, so this is not a complete solution. }
    S := SetupMessage(msgFinishedLabel);
    StringChange(S, '[name]', GetAppName(''));
    WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := S;
    WizardForm.AdjustLabelHeight(WizardForm.FinishedLabel);
  end;
end;
```

---

**Add/Remove Programs**

That's easy. There's [the `UninstallDisplayName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname) for this, which is resolved only during the actual installation, when we already know the selected components. So we can use your (fixed) `GetAppName` here:

```pascal
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayName={code:GetAppName}
```

---

**Are you sure you want to completely remove `AppName` and all of its components?**

You cannot change that. You better use some generic name in the `AppName` so that this message works for any component.

Or make the message not mention the application name at all:

```pascal
[Messages]
ConfirmUninstall=Are you sure you want to completely remove this game?
```

Alternatively remove the message completely:
[Replace or customize modal uninstallation windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023764/850848)

---

**Please wait while `AppName` is removed from your computer**

The same solution as for the `WizardForm.FinishedLabel`. Just use the `UninstallProgressForm.PageDescriptionLabel` from [the `InitializeUninstallProgressForm`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstallProgressForm).

---

**`AppName` was successfully removed from your computer**

Similar as with the *"Are you sure you want to completely remove `AppName` and all of its components?"*

Either make the `AppName` generic. Or disable the message with "silent" mode and implement your own message in [the `CurUninstallStepChanged(usPostUninstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged).
Again, see [Replace or customize modal uninstallation windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023764/850848).

---

For a similar discussion, see also [Changing AppName and AppDir depending on language in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6400598/850848).

Comment: I'll try this right now. As for Uninstall process, I need "Are you sure you want to completely remove....." message, "Please wait while `AppName` is removed from your computer" (PageDescriptionLabel), "Uninstalling `AppName...`" (StatusLabel), "`AppName` was successfully removed from your computer", and, if possible, the Uninstall Window Title

Comment: Also thanks for the hint on WizardSetupType. As I said before, I don't usually use types, so I didn't even know about this.

Comment: I thought you said it _was_ non-sense, that's why I deleted it.

Comment: It's nonsense to do, but can imagine that the question itself makes a perfect sense to novice user of Inno Setup. Please undelete it.

Comment: My bad. I'm not really sure how I can undelete it, though.

Comment: Undeleted the question.